# Не получается сделать проверку на существование значения в sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, sqlite3

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при вводе слова "Меню" бот спрашивал айди, потом соотносил его с базой, и если такой айди существует, то открывать меню администратора

Я не совсем понимаю, как такое можно сделать. Часть кода прилагаю

```
con = sqlite3.connect("dannie_2.db")
cur = con.cursor()
     
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM workers")

if message.text == "Меню":
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите id")
    id_work = message.text
    cur.execute("SELECT id FROM workers WHERE id=", id_work)
    need = cur.fetchall()
    print(need)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{need}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой код:

```
con = sqlite3.connect("dannie_2.db")
cur = con.cursor()
con.commit()

if message.text == "":
    id_work = message.text
    for need in cur.execut("SELECT id FROM workers WHERE id = '{}'".format(id_work)):
        need = need[0]
    con.commit()
    print(need)
```

Это должно работать, по крайней мере у меня так стоит, желаю вам удачи =)